# Relative noise level of tactile keyboards

Tags: keyboard, noise, peripherals

I'm hoping to replace my Apple aluminum keyboard with a more comfortable alternative. There are many great options out there—friends have recommended the [Das Keyboard](http://www.daskeyboard.com/) and the [Tactile Pro](http://matias.ca/tactilepro/)—and I think I'm ready to make the leap.

But, as a graduate student, I work in quiet, shared offices where other diligent workers are mere feet away. I know someone with a Tactile Pro and the typing clatter is distractingly loud. If you have heard one or more of these popular "tactile" keyboards in person, can you rank its noisiness with respect to other options?

Here are some keyboards I've heard of, but I'd also be interested in assessments of other models I haven't heard of yet:

- Das Keyboard [Model S Professional](http://www.daskeyboard.com/model-s-professional/) — the "loud" model with Cherry MX blue switches
- Das Keyboard [Model S Professional Silent](http://www.daskeyboard.com/model-s-professional-silent/) — the "quiet" model with Cherry MX brown switches
- Matias [Tactile Pro](http://matias.ca/tactilepro/)
- [Model M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_M_keyboard)
- [Apple aluminum keyboard](http://www.apple.com/keyboard/)
- The slightly older [Apple white plastic keyboard](http://www.mac-pro.com/New-Apple-Keyboard-White)
- Your typical junky keyboard from Dell or somesuch

Of the keyboards I've personally heard, I'd place the Apple aluminum keyboard as the quietest, the older Apple plastic keyboard and other OEM equipment as slightly louder, and the Tactile Pro as *far* louder than these two. Where do other keyboards fall on the spectrum?

(I've seen a few videos comparing keyboard noise, but I've found it impossible to glean much from these. [This one comparing the Das Keyboard clicky and silent models](http://www.daskeyboard.com/blog/?p=3000), for example, makes it seem like the two sound identical. I think placing the noises on a spectrum with keyboards I know from real life will be more helpful.)

Comment: If you're paying  through the roof to have a quiet computer like an apple laptop fanless quite powerful, costs a small fortune.. Then why not buy a bunch of keyboards and try them? very fast to try!  When something isn't completely noiseless, then opinions on how "quiet" things are very risky

Answer (score 2):

Step away from the traditional keyboard, and move to a flexible silicon keyboard like this [Inland Pro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026PTO7M), or this [DekCel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000K6ZNHE) or any number of others.  Or, if you need an Apple keyboard (you don't actually need it to be Apple specific since you can use any keyboard with a Mac) you can get this [bluetooth/wireless flexible keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003JIQA36).

You can expect any flexible keyboard to be quieter than a standard one.

Comment: In all my searches for a quiet keyboard, it never crossed my mind to go for a silicone, roll up one. Thank you very kindly for the suggestion! I purchased one now. I will post my experience with it in a separate comment. After having bought 3 supposedly "silent" keyboards, I was getting fed up. It's so annoying to watch video after video where the clearly paid reviewer talks about how silent a keyboard is, but when they finally press buttons on it (2-3 minutes into the video???), it sounds like someone is cracking their knuckles. I really hope this works.

Comment: THIS THING IS SILENT. It feels and sounds like I am tapping against skin lol. It is a weird sensation, and absolutely something to get used to. But for my purposes? This is a perfect fit. Thank you very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something provides a tactile feel, while also minimizing mechanical clicking and the plastic slapping when typing. Few commercial mechanical keyboards offer both of those options.

You want something like this with Cherry MX Clear (tactile bump, no sound): https://www.wasdkeyboards.com/wasd-v3-104-key-custom-mechanical-keyboard.html

With this addon:[image: Keyboard Addon]